# Use SQL CTE table to include path and all children

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have following hierarchical tree table

```
GO
DROP TABLE #tbl 
GO
CREATE TABLE #tbl (Id int , ParentId int)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (0, NULL)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (1, 0)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (2, 1)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (3, 1)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (4, 2)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (5, 2)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (6, 3)
INSERT  INTO #tbl (Id, ParentId) VALUES  (7, 3)
GO
```

Which maps to following tree

```
0
+- 1
   +- 2
      +- 4
      +- 5
   +- 3
      +- 6
      +- 7
```

Using CTE Recursive table, how can I get the path and also all children of the selected node. For example having `2` as input, how can I get following data (ordered if possible)

```
Id, ParentID
-------
 0, NULL 
 1, 0
 2, 1
 4, 2
 5, 2
```

I know I can traverse up in the tree (get path) with following statement

```
WITH RecursiveTree AS (
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *
        FROM #tbl
        WHERE Id = 2
    UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT Parent.*
        FROM 
            #tbl AS Parent
            JOIN RecursiveTree AS Child ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTree
```

And with following statement, traverse down in the tree (get all children)

```
WITH RecursiveTree AS (
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *
        FROM #tbl
        WHERE Id = 2
    UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT Child.*
        FROM 
            #tbl AS Child
            JOIN RecursiveTree AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.id
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTree
```

**Question:** How to combine these two commands into one?

Comment: +1 For providing good explanation, DDL, DML and test data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use UNION of these two selects

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7781a/8)

```
WITH RecursiveTree AS (
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *
        FROM #tbl
        WHERE Id = 2
    UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT Parent.*
        FROM 
            #tbl AS Parent
            JOIN RecursiveTree AS Child ON Child.ParentId = Parent.Id
),
RecursiveTree2 AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *
        FROM #tbl
        WHERE Id = 2
    UNION ALL
        -- Recursive Member
        SELECT Child.*
        FROM 
            #tbl AS Child
            JOIN RecursiveTree2 AS Parent ON Child.ParentId = Parent.id
)
select * from
(
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTree
union
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTree2
) t
order by id
```